# JMM in synchronized and volatile

Tags: java, java-memory-model

Many times I saw constructions like this one:

```
class OneTimeWriter {
    volatile Object o;

    void synchronized set(Object o) {
        if(this.o == null) this.o = o;
    }

    Object get() {
        return this.o;
    }
}
```

We have read/write membars at the begining/end of `synchronized` itself. So, can we remove `volatile` from o, since `synchronized` has release/acquire semantics itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless `get` is also `synchronized`; otherwise, there's no happens-before relationship between the setter putting something non-`null` into the field and the `get` call.

Comment: But, still, synchronized flushes writes to the main memory at the the end of setter. "o" should become visible to other threads. Or not?

Comment: Are you saying that `synchronized` will only update the executing thread's view of the variable, but not other threads which may only be calling `get`?

Comment: @Oroboros102 The `synchronized` setter will flush the write, and the non-null `o` is now *visible*, but there's no requirement for subsequent calls to `get` from other threads to refresh cached null values if they've already read it. Without a barrier on the read, the value is visible, but the other threads may not look.

Comment: Your last comment looks like the answer - I really missed that read barrier, that `volatile` gives us to getter thread. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization isn't absolute; it's always relative to another action. In the case of a `synchronized` block, the synchronization is between the closing of one `synchronized` block and the opening of a subsequent one on the same object.

Since your `get` method doesn't use `synchronized`, there is no happens-before relationship established between it and the `set` method. The getting thread could read a partially-set object put in by the setter, due to reorderings. For instance, if you put in `("Foo", 123)`, the getting thread could read that that same object as having state `(null, 123)`: the `123` state is there, but the `"Foo"` state hasn't yet been written (or flushed to this core's memory, etc).

Besides the `synchronized` block, another form of synchronization happens between the writing of a `volatile` field and the subsequent reading of that same field. That — and only that — is what provides the happens-before relationship you need in this case. The `synchronized` block in the setter only makes sure that `this.o` isn't set twice, nothing more.

Comment: AFAIK, reference write is atomic. So, we can not see partially written object - the reference is either written or not. On low level end of synchronized has write membar, so the reference should become visible to other threads right at the end of setter. Isn't it? What am I missing?

Comment: The reference write is atomic, yes, but that doesn't say anything about the memory that reference points to. So, if your object is at address `0xBEEFCAFE`, the field's value internally won't be `0xBEEF0000`; but an `int` value at memory address `0xBEEFCAFE+<fieldOffset>` could be `0` instead of `123`. As for the membar, the Java Memory Model doesn't specify that; it only specifies the happens-before relationships. Implementations are free to do whatever optimizations they want within the JMM rules.

Comment: Mostly correct, but the "partially-set object" is wrong. The field reference update will happen all at once, and the only way that you could see a partially-constructed object is if that object published itself unsafely, in which case the synchronization on this reference to it is completely orthogonal.

Comment: @chrylis I disagree with that latter part. The object is created on one thread and dereferenced on another thread, and that second thread got the reference without establishing a happens-before barrier (via a non-`volatile` `OneTimeWriter.o`). The only guarantees you have for the object's state are for its `final` fields.